Issues with applying VAT exemption only to products and not to shipping costs in WooCommerce
I'm having an issue with my WooCommerce store that I haven't been able to solve despite multiple attempts and code adjustments.
I want the VAT to be removed only from products and not from shipping costs when a valid VAT number (for EU businesses) is entered. Despite various code tweaks and settings adjustments, the VAT is being deducted from both products and shipping costs.
Current Code:
// JavaScript for validating UID and handling VAT exemption
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_script');
function custom_enqueue_script() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
        wp_add_inline_script('jquery', "
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                function showError(message, field) {
                    var errorElement = '<div class=\"validation-error\" style=\"color: red; font-weight: bold;\">' + message + '</div>';
                    if (field.next('.validation-error').length === 0) {
                        field.after(errorElement);
                    }
                }

                function removeError(field) {
                    field.next('.validation-error').remove();
                }

                function validateUID(country, uid) {
                    var regex;
                    var upperUID = uid.toUpperCase(); // Convert UID to uppercase
                    switch (country) {
                        case 'AT': regex = /^ATU[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'BE': regex = /^BE[0-9]{10}$/; break;
                        case 'BG': regex = /^BG[0-9]{9,10}$/; break;
                        case 'CY': regex = /^CY[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/; break;
                        case 'CZ': regex = /^CZ[0-9]{8,10}$/; break;
                        case 'DE': regex = /^DE[0-9]{9}$/; break;
                        case 'DK': regex = /^DK[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'EE': regex = /^EE[0-9]{9}$/; break;
                        case 'EL': regex = /^EL[0-9]{9}$/; break;
                        case 'ES': regex = /^ES[A-Z0-9][0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9]$/; break;
                        case 'FI': regex = /^FI[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'FR': regex = /^FR[A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{9}$/; break;
                        case 'HR': regex = /^HR[0-9]{11}$/; break;
                        case 'HU': regex = /^HU[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'IE': regex = /^IE[0-9][A-Z0-9+*][0-9]{5}[A-Z]{1,2}$/; break;
                        case 'IT': regex = /^IT[0-9]{11}$/; break;
                        case 'LT': regex = /^LT[0-9]{9,12}$/; break;
                        case 'LU': regex = /^LU[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'LV': regex = /^LV[0-9]{11}$/; break;
                        case 'MT': regex = /^MT[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'NL': regex = /^NL[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}$/; break;
                        case 'PL': regex = /^PL[0-9]{10}$/; break;
                        case 'PT': regex = /^PT[0-9]{9}$/; break;
                        case 'RO': regex = /^RO[0-9]{2,10}$/; break;
                        case 'SE': regex = /^SE[0-9]{12}$/; break;
                        case 'SI': regex = /^SI[0-9]{8}$/; break;
                        case 'SK': regex = /^SK[0-9]{10}$/; break;
                        default: return false;
                    }
                    return regex.test(upperUID);
                }

                function checkCompanyFields() {
                    var billing_company = $('#billing_company').val();
                    var billing_firma_uid = $('#billing_firma_uid').val();
                    var billing_country = $('#billing_country').val();

                    removeError($('#billing_company'));
                    removeError($('#billing_firma_uid'));

                    if (billing_company && !billing_firma_uid) {
                        showError('Please enter a VAT number if you fill in the company name.', $('#billing_firma_uid'));
                    } else if (!billing_company && billing_firma_uid) {
                        showError('Please enter a company name if you fill in the VAT number.', $('#billing_company'));
                    } else if (billing_firma_uid && !validateUID(billing_country, billing_firma_uid)) {
                        showError('Please enter a valid VAT number.', $('#billing_firma_uid'));
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '" . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . "',
                            data: {
                                action: 'check_company_field',
                                billing_company: billing_company,
                                billing_firma_uid: billing_firma_uid,
                                billing_country: billing_country,
                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                $('body').on('change', '#billing_company, #billing_firma_uid, #billing_country', function() {
                    checkCompanyFields();
                });

                checkCompanyFields();
            });
        ");
    }
}

// Handle the AJAX request to check the company field and set VAT exemption
add_action('wp_ajax_check_company_field', 'custom_check_company_field');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_company_field', 'custom_check_company_field');
function custom_check_company_field() {
    $eu_countries = array(
        'AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK'
    );

    $billing_country = isset($_POST['billing_country']) ? $_POST['billing_country'] : '';

    if (in_array($billing_country, $eu_countries) && isset($_POST['billing_company']) && !empty($_POST['billing_company']) && isset($_POST['billing_firma_uid']) && !empty($_POST['billing_firma_uid'])) {
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);
        write_log('VAT exempt set to true');
    } else {
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(false);
        write_log('VAT exempt set to false');
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    wp_die();
}

// Customize the tax class for products based on VAT exemption
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'customize_product_tax_class', 1, 2);
function customize_product_tax_class($tax_class, $product) {
    if (WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt() && !is_admin()) {
        write_log('Product tax class set to zero-rate for product: ' . $product->get_name());
        return 'zero-rate';
    }
    return $tax_class;
}

// Ensure shipping tax class is not affected by VAT exemption
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_tax_class', 'set_shipping_tax_class', 10, 2);
function set_shipping_tax_class($tax_class, $instance) {
    write_log('Shipping tax class set to standard for instance: ' . $instance->get_id());
    return 'standard'; // Set shipping tax class to standard
}

// Debugging the shipping tax rates
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'debug_shipping_tax_rates');
function debug_shipping_tax_rates() {
    $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
    foreach ($packages as $package) {
        foreach ($package['rates'] as $rate) {
            write_log('Shippin

I have implemented the provided code to validate the VAT number and apply VAT exemption in WooCommerce. I expected the VAT exemption to apply only to products and not to shipping costs. However, the VAT is being removed from both products and shipping costs. I have ensured that the shipping tax class is set to "Standard" and the product tax class for VAT exemption is set to "zero-rate". Despite these settings, the issue persists.

If you set a customer as "vat_exempt", no taxes are applied even for shipping regardless of your settings or code… So you have to use a different way, if you want to keep shipping taxes… You can use something like this adapting the code to your needs.
